# Synchornize linux clock without internet

Tags: linux, internet, clock

How can I keep a clock from a linux machine updated if this linux machine have no internet access?

The machine is in a network and others machine have internet access, but this particular one can't have.

Could I create a script to ask to another machine the correct time and put it on cron.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run an [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) servers on both computers.

On a computer with Internet access, set up global servers to query like this, in `/etc/ntp.conf` (use servers closest to you from [pool.ntp.org](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/)):

> server 0.us.pool.ntp.org
>   server 1.us.pool.ntp.org

On a computer *without* Internet access, use your local server set up above, e.g. in `/etc/ntp.conf` use

> server your.local.server.hostname

Strictly speaking, you don't have to use NTP server on a computer without Internet access, you can use something like `getdate` in a cron job, but NTP provides much more robust solution.